# jpeg and h264 formats

Tags: video, jpeg, h.264

What is the difference between h264 and jpeg?

Comment: Removed the C++ tag; no mention of any C++ here.

Comment: Actually the same difference as between movie and an image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

H.264 is a format for encoding video.  JPEG is a format for encoding still pictures.  Their implementations are completely different as well.

- [H.264 Specification (pdf)](http://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-H.264-200305-S!!PDF-E&type=items)
- [JPEG Specification (pdf)](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

h264 is a video codec, jpeg is an image-compression method and filetype.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG is an IMAGE codec whereas H264 is a VIDEO codec. JPEG encodes one frame/picture whereas H264, being a video codec, encodes a series of frames.